# Swagger "The method 'get' on path '../api/' is registered multiple times" error

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, swagger, openapi, nswag

I use OpenAPI / Swagger in an Angular app based on .NET Core and I encounter "The method 'get' on path '../api/' is registered multiple times" error when generating frontend code as TypeScript using NSwag Studio. As far as I see on Github pages, etc. the problem is related to using the same route even if the method names in the API or Controller are not same as shown below:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<DemoDto>> Get()
{
    return await Mediator.Send(new GetDemoQuery()); // GetDemoQuery()
}

[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<DemoDto> GetById(int id)
{
    return await Mediator.Send(new GetGetDemoByIdQuery { Id = id }); // GetGetDemoByIdQuery()
}
```

So, is there any fix to solve the problem except? I already use different names as the method names, but encounter this problem.

***Update:*** Here is my route definition in Startup.cs (I use .NET MVC before, and I think route definitions for .NET Core is set in Startup.cs as something like on [ASP.NET Core - Routing](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_core/asp.net_core_routing.htm). But in my app, the only route setting in Startuo.cs is the following:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

Is there anything to apply extra?
So, is there anything

Comment: How are your routes defined? Did you confirm that calling `/{id}` actually hits the second endpoint?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks for reply, I added update. Could you pls have a look at?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Should I add something like `[Route("api/[controller]/{id}")]` to the `ApiController`? Now it has `[Route("api/[controller]")]` juts below the `[ApiController]` annotation. Any idea?

Comment: You didn't answer my second question, does the endpoint work?

Comment: I could not test it as I do not generate the frontend code. But normally, when I change its name, yes it could work.

Comment: You don't need a front-end, just open your browser and go to the appropriate URL

Comment: I know, but as I cannot build the app, I cannot run it :( Any other think that I can do assuming the endpoint works?

Comment: Ok, I make it run and both endpoints are working (I tests using Swagger page). So, what should I do next?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot help you more, as I have never used nswag. I wanted to make sure your routes actually worked in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, but is the route config ok in my app? Can we check it?

Comment: Swagger works, so the problem is in nswag, not in your server code

Comment: Thanks for help, I fixed the problem but I am not sure if there is a better usage for this. Could you have  a look at my answer pls?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding `[Route("Demo/Get/{id?}")]` annotation. I hope the usage is correct and there is not a short or smarter way for this usage.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("mycontroller")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<DemoDto>> Get()
{
    return await Mediator.Send(new GetDemoQuery()); // GetDemoQuery()
}

[HttpGet("{id}")]
[Route("mycontroller/{id?}")]
public async Task<DemoDto> GetById(int id)
{
    return await Mediator.Send(new GetGetDemoByIdQuery { Id = id }); // GetGetDemoByIdQuery()
}
```